# What is the prettiest way to convert time_point to string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14, c++-chrono

Simple question, how to properly convert `std::chrono::time_point` to a `std::string` with as little code as possible?

Notes: I don't want to use `cout` it with `put_time()`. C++11 and C++14 solutions are accepted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide code representing Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your task? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Davic C. glad to be here. I dont have code that i need to debug or task to finish, i want to find appropriate and elegant solution that i can use in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <type_traits>

int
main()
{
    auto s = date::format("%F %T", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(s), std::string>, "");
}
```

`date/date.h` is found [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  It is a header-only library, C++11/14/17.  It has [written documentation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), and a [video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo).

### Update:

In C++20 the syntax is:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <type_traits>

int
main()
{
    auto s = std::format("{:%F %T}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s), std::string>{});
}
```

Comment: Hi @Howard, Thank you for making date library it seems like great code and i will for sure dive into it (and probably use it), but for this question i want to find solution that uses standard libraries.

Comment: I understand, and good luck in your search.  One such strategy is go on vacation for a few years and *maybe* when you come back, this *will* *be* part of the standard library. ;-)  [Proposal](https://wg21.link/p0355)

Comment: I hope it does, we need something like this. :)

Answer (score 6):

Using only standard library headers (works with >= C++11):

```
    #include <ctime>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <string>
  
    using sc = std::chrono::system_clock ;
    std::time_t t = sc::to_time_t(sc::now());
    char buf[20];
    strftime(buf, 20, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&t));
    std::string s(buf);
```

Comment: This is so much C like syntax, i will just accept Howard answer.