# C++ namespace "std" has no member "format" despite #include <format>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, fmt

I am new to C++. I am trying to store the current date and time as a string variable.

At [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217017/), I found an answer, and installed the `date.h` library.

However, when I try to use the code provided, I am met with the error:

> namespace "std" has no member "format"

Despite having `#include <format>` at the top of the script.

How can I fix this?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, if that helps.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <date.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <format>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "The current time is ";
    auto start_time = std::format("{:%F %T}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(start_time), std::string>{});
    std::cout << start_time << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is c++20 enabled?

Comment: Did you enable `/std=c++latest`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In the C/C++ compiler settings `C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard` at least that is where this setting is in Visual Studio 2019. I don't have 2022

Comment: @Enderbyte09 see [MSVC C++20 and the /std:c++20 Switch](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/)

Comment: "Despite having #include <format> at the top of the script" - C++ is not a scripting language and C++ source files are not "scripts". For your future benefit; read up on terminology and the difference between scripting languages and compiled languages.

Comment: On MacOS, Xcode 15.3  includes support for std::format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::format` was added to C++ in the C++20 standard. Unless you compile with C++20, you won't have `std::format`.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/)

Comment: As stated in other answers, compiling with "ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)" doesn't work in Visual Studio 2022. You need to set "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)".

Answer (score 11):

As of december of 2021, the `std::format` and some other `C++20` facilities are available only under `/std:c++latest` mode in **Visual Studio 2019** and **2022**.

[Here is a quote:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/)

> As part of implementing C++20, there were some late discoveries which
> required changes to the ISO C++20 standard via the standard
> committee’s Defect Report (DR) process. This included Existing
> implementations (pre-DR) for these features are available under the
> /std:c++latest switch.  We’re also tracking the DRs and are
> implementing those issue resolutions under /std:c++latest. Our plan is
> to make these capabilities available under the /std:c++20 switch after
> implementation of the full set of Standard Library DRs has completed.

When Microsoft finishes implementing all DRs, the `std::format` will be available under the `/std:c++20` switch.

Answer (score 6):

For those running into this issue, using GCC or clang. The compiler only has partial support for all the new modules in c++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Answer (score 4):

Format as a part of std is only implemented on clang++ and MSVC for now. So to make it work on other compilers such as g++, apple clang, use [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) which is the implementation of format.

Download the `fmt` package and place it in `src` folder along with your files and include it at compilation also specify that you are using c++ 20.

You can use it like this for reference:

```
g++ -I fmt/include -std=c++20 main.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Post here since this is the top result in google "error C2039: 'format_string': is not a member of 'std'". In case someone else having same issue.

So it's not exact same to original question. In my case, `std::format` is working perfectly in VS2022, but not `std::format_string` or `std::wformat_string`.

I have tried all suggestions and solutions online but then finally find out it's  because in the old version MSVC (14.34.31933) the `format` header implement the feature with a different name:

```
template <class... _Args>
using _Fmt_string = _Basic_format_string<char, type_identity_t<_Args>...>;
```

But in latest version (14.36.32532), it's changed to `format_string`.